# Constantly getting "IOException: Access Denied" when trying to call SQLite driver

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, liferay

I'm trying, with Liferay 7 bundled with Tomcat, to access to a SQLite database for testing purposes. The database is an empty "test.db" file located at C:/Eclipse, folder which has absolute control to the system account "All accounts". So windows permissions shouldn't be a problem.

This code, located at the render method of my portlet, somehow throws an IOException:

```
@Override
public void render(RenderRequest arg0, RenderResponse arg1) throws IOException, PortletException {
    try {
        Conector.test();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("ERROR SQLITE: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    super.render(arg0, arg1);
}
```

T

The code that performs the task just tries to access the .db file, create some tables and perform a single query, just to see that everything is connected so I'm able to do further things, is this:

```
 public static void test() throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
      /**
         * Connect to a sample database
         */

            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                // db parameters
                String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Eclipse\\test.db";
                // create a connection to the database
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

                System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (conn != null) {
                        conn.close();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Internal sqlite error: "+ex.getMessage());
                }
            }

  }
```

But somehow, I keep getting this error (spanish mode):

> java.io.IOException: Acceso denegado  at
>   java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)    at
>   com.db.Conector.test(Conector.java:24)    at
>   com.test.PortletMVC.render(PortletMVC.java:25)    at
>   com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
>   (many, many more lines. Typical Liferay).

What's happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the connection URL with slashes? I mean "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Eclipse/test.db"?

Comment: By the way, your stacktrace doesn't match your code: There is not `File.createNewFile` call in your `Conector.test` method...

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it the username and password. Use DriverManager.getConnection(url, YOUR_USERNAME, YOUR_PASSWORD)

Comment: The access denied is on a file system level, so this is not likely the cause of the error.